# Integrating payu payment gateway (active_merchant_payu_in) with spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I am trying to integrate payu.in payment gateway with spree into my rails application. I have included gem 'active_merchant_payu_in' in the application.

My app/models/spree/gateway/payu.rb looks like this:

```
module Spree
  class Gateway::Payu < Gateway
    def provider_class
      ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::PayuIn
    end
  end
end
```

In application.rb

```
config.after_initialize do |app|
  app.config.spree.payment_methods += [
    Spree::Gateway::Payu
  ]
end
```

Development.rb

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test    
  $payu_merchant_id = ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::PayuIn.merchant_id = '--ID--'
  $payu_secret_key = ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::PayuIn.secret_key = '--Key--'    
end
```

I have enabled Spree::Gateway::Payu from admin credentials. Now when i do a checkout i get below error.

**NoMethodError in Spree::CheckoutController#update
undefined method `authorize' for ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::PayuIn:Module**

can someone guide me towards right path.
Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone is still facing this problem.

Solution: Edit your payment method "Spree::Gateway::Payu" and set `auto_capture?` field to `true`.

Payu does not support authorize method which is called when "auto capture" is set to `false`, when set to `true`, "purchase" method is called which is supported by payu.

You can read more about auto capture in Spree's documentation. https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/payments.html